# How to write a generic method in Java

Tags: c#, java, generics

How to write a generic method in Java.

In C# I would do this

```
    public static T Resolve<T>()
    {
        return (T) new object();
    }
```

Whats the equivalent in Java?

Comment: Your C# code throws an InvalidCastException if `T` does not happen to be `object`.

Comment: your c# generic method is not a good example since for almost any value of T that cast will throw.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, your C# example is wrong; it will throw an `InvalidCastException` unless `typeof(T) == typeof(object)`. You can fix it by adding a [constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

```
public static T Resolve<T>() where T : new() {
    return new T();
}
```

Now, this would be the equivalent syntax in Java (or, at least, as close as we can get):

```
public static <T> T Resolve() {
    return (T) new T();
}
```

Notice the double mention of `T` in the declaration: one is the `T` in `<T>` which parameterizes the method, and the second is the return type `T`.

Unfortunately, the above does not work in Java. Because of the way that Java generics are implemented runtime type information about `T` is not available and so the above gives a compile-time error. Now, you can work around this constraint like so:

```
public static <T> T Resolve(Class<T> c) {
    return c.newInstance();
}
```

Note the need to pass in `T.class`. This is known as a [runtime type token](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html). It is the idiomatic way of handling this situation.

Comment: That's going to throw some exceptions! Don't use reflection in these cases.

Comment: @tackline: No, this is idiomatic Java for handling this situation: cf. http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/literals.html

Comment: "First, your C# example is wrong". I do not think it is wrong for a method to throw an exception in certain situations (OP's example)(especially in a question about syntax). I do however think it is wrong for a method not to compile (your C# example). You forgot the `<T>` after `Resolve`.

Answer (score 2):

As other commenters have pointed out, you can do this with Java as well - with as much of a possibility to create a casting exception at runtime:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T resolve() {
  return (T) new Object();
}
```

Unless you use the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation, however, Java's *type erasure* comes into play and you will get a compiler warning. The exception will also occur somewhere else: whereever you are trying to use it:

```
String s = <String>resolve();
```

will throw the exception.

On the other hand, you probably wanted to use `new T()` in C# anyway. This you cannot do in Java. The suggested workaround is to use `Class<T>` as a type parameter if you need to rely on type information at runtime. For your example, this would mean that you have to refactor it to this version:

```
public static <T> T resolve(Class<T> type) {
  try {
    return type.newInstance();
  } catch(Exception e) {
    // deal with the exceptions that can happen if 
    // the type doesn't have a public default constructor
    // (something you could write as where T : new() in C#)
  }
}
```

By the way, you can use this also to get rid of the warning in the previous case and to place the runtime exception at a more sensible line:

```
public static <T> T resolve(Class<T> type) {
  return type.cast(new Object());
}
```

This piece of code will behave exactly like the one you gave as an example - including an exception that occurs when `T` is any type different from `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

```
 public static <T> T Resolve()
    {
        return (T) new Object();
    }
```

Be careful about `(T)` but I am not sure that this is correct. I know that generic cast causes a lot of problems. I have already spent with it a lot of time...

Comment: This works ok in Java because T is erased to Object at compile time.  However you really aren't getting any type-safety out of this implementation.

Comment: @ GreyMatter 9: Right, the Resolve method provokes an  java.lang.ClassCastException if T is any other type than java.lang.Object.

Comment: The CCE is actually thrown from the call site, not this method. (But that is pedantry.)

Comment: +1 this is the best answer imho. I don't think this question is about creating an instance of a type provided as a parameter through generics... I think it's just about the syntax of a generic method....

Answer (score 0):

You want some kind of factory:

```
 public interface MyFactory<T> {
     T newInstance();
 }
```

Then that can be passed into where it is needed. In your code:

```
public static T resolve<T>(MyFactory<T> factory) {
    return factory.newInstance();
}
```

Note: There is absolutely no reason to be using reflection for this!!

Comment: How is newInstance written inside MyFactory<T>. Surely that must use reflection to create the new instance? (Sorry, transitioning from C# to Java still).

Comment: Scratch that question. I see the java class type (java.lang.Class) has a newInstance() method to generate a new instance where there's a parameterless constructor.

Comment: @Lisa You really don't want to be touching reflection if you can help it. Implementations of `MyFactory` can construct a specific `T` as they see fit.